# VBA Radio buttons: Select at least one option

Tags: vba, excel, button, userform

I have a userform with with 6 different categories in which the user must select an option between 0-4. Each option is selectable with a radio button with a set value that will be written in the parent sheet. Each set of radio buttons that belong to a category are grouped (a-e).

Could someone please help me to implement a mechanism that will make it mandatory for the user to select at one option in each category by displaying a message prompting the user to select an option?

The workflow is as such:

User selects options --> Selected options are written in the sheet --> `Unload Me` on the form

Ideally it would be best if the macro to write all is "paused" (not proceeding to `Unload Me`). Instead the message is displayed, and then the form remains as it was so that the user can go back and continue, without having to redo the whole process.

EDIT:

Thanks for all help. Hope this makes it easier:

The code I'm using is being triggered by a "Register score" button that I've placed on the UserForm that contains all the radio buttons. The button contains the following code (where **aa** = first radio button):

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
If aa.Value = False Then
MsgBox ("Please select at least one option")
Else
Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = "Category A"
Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = "0"
End If
Unload Me
End sub
```

I now repeat this code for every radio button. Problem is, if the user for example selects a radio button properly in every category but forgets the first, the form will reset meaning that the user must re-do the entire thing. I can of course also add (I've only included the radio buttons here for sake of simplicity, but the correct code would of course include **all** buttons):

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
If aa.Value = False and ab.Value = False And ac.Value = False Then
MsgBox ("Please select at least one option")
```

In this case the user must select one option every category, but it will also reset the entire form, meaning that you have to redo everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like:

```
If Radio1.value = False And Radio2.value = False And Radio3.value = False And Radio4.value = False then
  Msgbox "Please select something from the first four Radio Buttons"
Exit Sub
End if
```

Comment: Thanks. I did a variation of that with the following:
`If Radio1.value = False then  
MsgBox ("Please select one option")  
Else  
If Radio.Value = true then  
xxxxxxx  
Else  
'do nothing  
End If  
End If`

Comment: If you found my answer useful, could you mark it as such please... thanks.

Comment: Oh sorry. Forgot to ask a follow-up on that. Using this method partially solves the problem, but it unloads the form if `If Radio.value = false`. Is there a way to reset the macro without the form unloading?

Comment: You might have to change the Exit Sub for a Go To Label, so the subroutine carries on from where your label is based...

Comment: You could replace the Exit Sub for "GoTo LabelName" and then have "LabelName:" where you want your code to continue from... Hope this makes sense, it is very difficult to give you better recommendations without seeing your actual code...

Comment: Thanks for all the help, I'll update my OP so you can see what I've done so far.

Comment: You didn't include the piece of code that resets the form, are you still using the Exit Sub? or have you tried using the GoTo Label to bypass the unselected Radio button?

Comment: I've added the last two lines in the first segment in OP.

I don't really know how to make that code, that's part of my problem. I'm still using Unload Me & End Sub. If I use GoTo, I merely loop the macro all the time since the macro starts once the button is pressed. I don't really know how to "unpress" the button without interrupting the whole routine, thereby also resetting the entire form.

Comment: Remove the Unload Me and after the msgbox before the Else put Exit Sub... I think that should do the job... Try that and let me know how you get on...

Comment: Thanks, that partially solved it (marked your answer as solution). Unfortunately it causes problems with the rest of my code as `Unload Me` made sure that everything gets registered just once and the form closes when complete, now a user can press the button several times over.

Do you know if it's possible to call an entire group of radio buttons? That way I can use for example `If group1.value = true then`

Comment: Well instead of doing a Group1.value = true, you simply replace that with a series of "If Radio1.value = True OR Radio2.value = true Or Radio3.value = true then" like on the answer I posted...

Comment: I did that, but what I'm trying to do is `If Group1.value = true then Unload me Else`. Repeat this for all groups, and the unload me will be active only if the user has select one option in each group. Since each category contains several options, I have to write a line for each possible combination for all categories. That's a lot of code. I though it's easier to do a line for the entire group, since that will cover all combinations possible.

Comment: I've never combined them as you mention, but its not that much more code, simply one line with all the options per group of radio buttons, so if you have four groups with however many options in each group, it will only be an IF statement for each of the groups, meaning four IF statements...

Answer (score 1):

To ensure one is selected simply add a section of code in the OK/Close button's event that checks that at least one button is selected - if not display message and then either Exit Sub to abort the routine, or implement the checks as a function that returns a boolean and only unload if it returns true.

Incidentally, on your proposed workflow, if you unload the form how are you going to then write the user's choices into the sheet?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That's what I'm trying to do, but I actually don't know how.

I saw an earlier post using  {If IsNull} but I can't figure out how to apply it to an entire group.

Regarding the workflow, I actually wrote wrong. Thanks for pointing that out. I'll fix it in the OP.